# Udp socket binding failed

Tags: ios, c, node.js, sockets

I am trying to connect a UDP server running on Node.js using

```
int socketDs = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);

struct sockaddr_in socket;
memset(&socket, 0, sizeof(socket));
socket.sin_family = AF_INET;
socket.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("SERVER.IP");
socket.sin_port = htons(PORT);

long r = bind(socketDs, (struct sockaddr *)&socket, sizeof(socket));
NSLog(@"Sockect bind: %ld   %s", r, strerror(errno));
```

Couldn't bind to it, returns with `Can't assign requested address`. However sendto is working fine without binding to it.

What could be the issue. Also I am not getting 'close' event to on node.js

Here is my server code

```
var dgram = require("dgram");
var server = dgram.createSocket("udp4");

var clients = new Array();

server.on("listening", function () {
    var address = server.address();
    console.log("UDP Server listening on " + address.address + ":" + address.port);
});

server.on("message", function (message, remote) {
    console.log(remote.address + ':' + remote.port +' - ' + message);
    }
});

server.on("close") {
    console.log("close");
});

server.on("error") {
    console.log("error");
});

server.bind(PORT);
```

Comment: Show us the definition of `SERVER.IP`

Comment: It is valid IPv4 ip like "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"

Comment: @DawoodMujib Why not show the value of it then? You're very likely behind a NAT and binding to a local address, so it's not like we'll get to know your public IP this way.

Comment: It is my server ip "46.243.150.19". well it's not behind the NAT

Comment: Just a guess. The question is ambiguous. By any chance the code you show first, is that client code? In client why are you binding to server IP? (I guess so because you mention `sendto` is fine.

Comment: Yup, first one is client side code

Comment: Are you running on the machine with the IP you're trying to bind to, or is the IP on the remote machine?

Comment: I am trying to bind with the IP of a remote machine.

Answer (score 0):

The first piece of code, you mentioned is that of client. And you are trying to bind to SERVER_IP. This obviously will lead to `bind` error that you see. You are trying to tie the client to an IP that belongs to an external system.

And `sendto` is fine because there is implicit bind on the client side.

Clients need not `bind` explicitly. You can do away with that part.